# How to remove empty (or filled with incorrect data) fields

Tags: c++, arrays

As I have read, the C++ compiler initialize table with the random data, before I initialize it by myself.
I've got a program which after performing (for example) give me this output - char table.

```
{'D','K','2','EMPTY FIELD','1','+','EMPTY FIELD','EMPTY FIELD','3','EMPTY FIELD','/'}
```

Now I would like to delete whole inconvenient data like letters, and empty fields.
I'm trying to achieve this by this code, but I think it transfer it into ASCII code. Am I able to achieve this in another way ?

```
char wynik[20];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <20; i++)
{
    if (wyjscie[i] == '+' || wyjscie[i] == '-' || wyjscie[i] == '/' || wyjscie[i] == '*' || (wyjscie[i] >-241241 || wyjscie[i] < 2141242142 ))
    {
        wynik[j] = wyjscie[i];
            j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this supposed to do `(wyjscie[i] >-241241 || wyjscie[i] < 2141242142 )`?

Comment: Condition that should pass integer values

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a misunderstanding of what a character is and not likely to be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

`(wyjscie[i] >-241241 || wyjscie[i] < 2141242142 )` is your problem. You're confusing the integer values represented by a character and the integer codes of characters. If you want to check if a character `c` is between 0 and 9 you could do `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`.

Comment: What if the character c is between -1000 and 1000 ?

Comment: A character is only one character. 1000 is 4 characters.